# Laravel eloquent Too few arguments to function 1 passed & 2 expected in my query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

**Here my code :**

```php
 $sum = $pipes->sum(function ($pipe) use ($filter) {
            $total = 0;
            $items = $pipe->items
                ->where('status', 'Terminé')
                ->where('closed', false)
                ->where(function ($qu) use ($filter) {
                    if ($filter === false) {
                        $qu->where('payment_id', 'exists', false)
                            ->where('closed', false)
                            ->where('locker', 'exists', false);
                    } else {
                        $qu->where('payment_id', 'exists', true)
                            ->where('closed', false)
                            ->where('locker', 'exists', false)
                            ->where('failed_to_pay', true);
                    }
                })->get();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $total = $total + ($item->price * $item->quantity);
            }

            return $total;
        });
```

The error is about the line of the `->get();`

Anyone have an idea to resolve the problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: `$pipes->sum` ? to `$pipes->map` ??

Comment: Same problem with map @Hamelraj

Comment: what if you only just get the items with these conditions.?

Comment: What do you mean ? @hasan05

Comment: May be the problem is here `->where(function ($qu) use ($filter) {`. hense where condition needs two parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know `->where(function ($qu) use ($filter))` about this where condition  but you can simple Try this

```php
  $sum = $pipes->sum(function ($pipe) use ($filter) {
            $total = 0;
            $itemsQ = $pipe->items
                ->where('status', 'Terminé')
                ->where('closed', false);

                if($filter == false) {
                   $items = $itemsQ->where('payment_id', 'exists', false)
                    ->where('closed', false)
                    ->where('locker', 'exists', false)->get();
                }else {
                    $items = $itemsQ->where('payment_id', 'exists', true)
                    ->where('closed', false)
                    ->where('locker', 'exists', false)
                    ->where('failed_to_pay', true)->get();

                }

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $total = $total + ($item->price * $item->quantity);
            }

            return $total;
        });
```

don't add that many arguments in `where()` function rather create instance  of `items` and add query based upon condition